# Ajax PHP Follow Script - Nothing stored in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I recently discovered a treehouse blog on ajax for beginners http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php I've been looking for a follow script for a while and I've hit a dead end. Currently the follow button fades as it should do, yet no values are stored in the database as of yet.

Profile.php (follow button):

```
          <div id="followbtncontainer" class="btncontainer"><a href="#" id="followbtn" class="bigblue">Follow</a></div>
```

Ajax.js

```
    $(function(){
  $('#followbtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#followbtn').fadeOut(300);

    $.ajax({
      url: '../ajax-follow.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'action': 'follow'},
      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "ok") {
          $('#followbtncontainer').html('<p><em>Following!</em></p>');
          var numfollowers = parseInt($('#followercnt').html()) + 1;
          $('#followercnt').html(numfollowers);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });

  $('body').on('click', '#morefllwrs', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $('#loadmorefollowers');

    $(container).html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');
    var newhtml = '';

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax-followers.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'page': $(this).attr('href')},
      cache: false,
      success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
          if(typeof item == 'object') {
          newhtml += '<div class="user"> <a href="#" class="clearfix"> <img src="'+item.profile_pic+'" class="avi"> <h4>'+item.username+'</h4></a></div>';
          } 
          else {
            return false;
          }
        }) // end $.each() loop

        if(json.nextpage != 'end') {
          // if the nextpage is any other value other than end, we add the next page link
          $(container).html('<a href="'+json.nextpage+'" id="morefllwrs" class="bigblue thinblue">Load more followers</a>');
        } else {
          $(container).html('<p></p>');
        }

        $('#followers').append(newhtml);
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
});
```

ajax.php

```
    <?php require 'database.php' //<?php include 'session-check-index.php' ?>
<?php include 'authentication.php' ?>
<?php
    session_start();
$follower=$_SESSION['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql);
    $rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$following=$rws['id'];

/**
 * this script will auto-follow the user and update their followers count
 * check out your POST data with var_dump($_POST)
**/



if($_POST['action'] == "follow") {

$sql=" INSERT INTO `user_follow` (`follower`, `following`, `subscribed`) VALUES ('$follower', '$following', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"
  /**
   * we can pass any action like block, follow, unfollow, send PM....
   * if we get a 'follow' action then we could take the user ID and create a SQL command
   * but with no database, we can simply assume the follow action has been completed and return 'ok'
  **/
   mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));

}

?>
```

I'm not sure if the actual $following and $follower values are causing the problem, and just not passing any data. Any help would be much appreciated,  thanks!

Comment: you only send a `page` parameter in your POST request, i cant see an `action` parameter

Comment: Which `$.ajax()` callback is firing post call? `success` or `error`? And in your `success` callback you're running the following: `if(data == "ok") {` yet you're not sending back `ok` in the response, so that condition will never satisfy. But that last part won't affect whether data is inserted to the database. Just an FYI

Comment: In your `SELECT` query within `ajax.php` where are you getting `$username` from? Is it being set? Since your `INSERT` is strictly dependant on your `SELECT` being successful, and returning a value for `$following`, you should really add a constraint of sorts on the two.

Comment: Small typographic clarification: you're posting to `ajax-follow.php` yet your question refers to the page as `ajax.php`

Comment: @messerbill so the action parameter isn't actually running anything? This is the bit I don't understand, the example just assumed you were already connected to the db so didn't fully explain what needed to be added to the action parameter

Comment: let's continue this conversation in the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113624/james-messerbill

Answer (score -1):

try to change in ajax.js

```
$(function(){
    $('#followbtn').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#followbtn').fadeOut(300);

       $.ajax({
           url: '../ajax-follow.php',
           ...
```

the url parameter to :

```
url: 'ajax-follow.php',
```

See if it will work that way

Comment: You may be right, but why do you assume the files are in the same directory?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII you are right, but I saw the other `url: 'ajax-follwer.php'` below and assumed that the files are in the same folder. The button is fading because the function is called before the ajax request , and thought that there is something wrong with the url . Maybe if using browser developer tools will tell us more about it

Comment: my bad `url: 'ajax-followers.php',`... sorry for the mistake